# Toogle class of other divs except the one clicked

Tags: jquery, css, toggle

There are several links/images on a website. I have a box that popups when you click on a link/image. Now the other links/images should "dim out" while the one clicked should stay the same.
Currently I have following script:

HTML Boxcontent

```
<div id="boxid1" class="modal-box">
 Content Box 1
</div>

<div id="boxid2" class="modal-box">
 Content Box 2
</div>
```

HTML Links

```
<div class="container a">
 Content
 <a class="linkid1">Test</a>
</div>

<div class="container b">
 Content
 <a class="linkid1">Test</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.modal-box { display: none; }
.dim { background: blue; }
```

```
$('.linkid1').click(function(e){
    $('.container').not('.a').toggleClass('dim');
    $('#boxid1').toggle();
});

$('.linkid2').click(function(e){
    $('.container').not('.b').toggleClass('dim');
    $('#boxid2').toggle();
});
```

This works but very possibly (I'm a novice) is bad and too "complicated". How can I streamline this?

Follow Up: Would this also be possible to achieve without javascript and just css? Like https://jsfiddle.net/wcvtesor/ but with the "features" described above

Comment: $('.container > .linkid1').click(function(e){
  $(this).removeClass('dim').parent().siblings().find('.linkid1').addClass('dim');
}); ?

Comment: @VXp `this` would be the clicked `<a>` element. `.parent().siblings().find('.linkid1')` would then find nothing at all because there's only one `.linkid1` element (`this`). And what about the modal?

Comment: I can see that both a's have the same class, don't you? It's working perfectly fine... If you want to put it on container, then $('.container').click(function(e){
  $(this).removeClass('dim').siblings().addClass('dim');
}); And about the modal, I overlooked that part at first, maybe later...

Comment: @VXp `$('.linkid2').click(...)` so the second `class="linkid1"` is most likely a typo

Comment: yeah, typo. And unfortunately (this) doesn't work, I also tried that :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This works but very possibly (I'm a novice) is bad and too "complicated"

If it works for you then it's not bad or complicated. There might be room for improvement but this is almost always the case ;)

> How can I streamline this?

You could use an event handler that works relative to the clicked element.

For this we would also have to make a small change on the `.container`s:

```html
<div class="container" data-modal-id="boxid1">
 Content 1
 <a>Test 1</a>
</div>
<div class="container" data-modal-id="boxid2">
 Content 2
 <a>Test 2</a>
</div>
```

We store the id of the related `.modal` in a `data-*` attribute on the container. We also no longer need the classes `a` and `b` for the different containers, nor the class for the `<a>` element.

With this we then can modify the event handler into this:

```js
$(".container a").on("click", function() {
  const container = $(this).closest(".container"), // the current container
        modalId = container.data("modal-id");      // the id of the modal for this container

  $(".container").not(container)       // select all .container and remove the current one
                 .toggleClass("dim");  // toggle the class on the remaining containers

  $("#" + modalId).toggle();           // toggle the modal
});
```

All combined:

```js
$(".container a").on("click", function() {
  const container = $(this).closest(".container"),
        modalId = container.data("modal-id");

  $(".container").not(container).toggleClass("dim");
  
  $("#" + modalId).toggle();
});
```

```css
.modal-box { display: none; }
.dim { background: blue; color: white; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" data-modal-id="boxid1">
 Content 1
 <a>Test 1</a>
</div>
<div class="container" data-modal-id="boxid2">
 Content 2
 <a>Test 2</a>
</div>

<div id="boxid1" class="modal-box">
 Content Box 1
</div>
<div id="boxid2" class="modal-box">
 Content Box 2
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Only thing now is that it's the other way around I think, so when clicking "Test 1" all other contents (Test 2, 3 etc) should dim out

Comment: Thank you! One last thing. How would it possible to close the box whenever clicking anywhere (not just when clickin on the link itself)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element

Answer (score 1):

What actually wants to do I did not get your problems but using data-x for target content box and this pointer you can easily solve your problem.

```js
$(function(){
$('.linkid1').click(function(e){
  var $parent=$(this).closest('.container');  
$('.container').not($parent).toggleClass('dim');
    $('#'+$(this).attr('data-target')).toggle();
});

});
```

```css
.modal-box { display: none; }
.dim { background: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="boxid1" class="modal-box">
 Content Box 1
</div>

<div  id="boxid2" class="modal-box">
 Content Box 2
</div>
<div  class="container">
 Content 1
 <a data-target="boxid1" class="linkid1">Test</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
 Content 2
 <a data-target="boxid2" class="linkid1">Test</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfect. What would I have to do to close those popup boxes whenever you click anywhere (except the box itself)?

Comment: To close those pop-up need to add an event listener in body.

Comment: To close those pop-up need to add an event listener in body. Sample code  $('body').on('click', function (e) {
            let $tar = $(e.target);
            if ($tar.closest('.container').length === 0) { // if click box is not a container then hide modal box
                $('.modal-box').hide();
            }
        });